# Need some explanation to really understand how for loop/binary works in this specific example(JAVA)

Tags: java, binary

```
public class fpNumbers {   
    public static void main(String args[])   {     
        int i;     
        double d = 0.1; 
        for(i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {       
            System.out.println(1.0 + d);
            d = d / 10;     
        } 
    }  
}
```

For the above code, the question is why does the result become 1,0 after a few iterations.

But before that I want to find out what is actually happening anyways. I understand how for loops work  (at least I think so), but the `i++` means +1 is added to `i` every turn.  But why does `i` disappear after that and what's the reason for the `System.out.println(1.0 + d);` then.... 1.0 has nothing to do with `i` right and `d` is also `d = d / 10`? Doesn't make sense to me how a variable is itself divided by 10, shouldn't that create an infinite loop?

Comment: This sounds like a *great* opportunity to step through the code in a debugger.  With a debugger you can observe the code, line by line, as it executes.  See the behavior, see how variable values change with each line, etc.  A debugger will likely be your most valuable tool in programming.  When you use your debugger and observe this code, what specific behavior are you observing on what specific line and why is that behavior unexpected?

Answer (score 1):

1. i does not disappear. If you add a System.out.println(i); after the for loop you will see i is 21.
2. A double can only have 15 decimal places. Everything less than 0.000000000000001 will not be stored by this primitive. After deviding 0.1 20 times it will just be zero. So don't be surprised if the console shows "1.0". You added 0 to 1.
3. Why should d = d/10 cause an infinite loop? The value will be divided by 10 exactly 1 time. If I have a bowl with an apple in it and replace the apple with itself cutted into 10 pieces I won't recieve infinite pieces, too.

Comment: You're totally right, thanks for the explanations. Since i m new in java i had an issue with the "=" operator , i thought it translated to the same as in math

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the result becoming 1.0 after a few iterations is that double has 15 significant digits, which limits its precision.

After few iterations, you have a number 1.0000000000000001, which requires 16 significant digits and double can not represent it, so it "cuts" it.

If for example, you changed `println()` line to the following,

```
System.out.println(d);
```

You would see correct results, because these numbers require only 1 significant digit.

To learn more about double and significant digits, I would recommend

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Secondly `d = d / 10` wouldn't cause infinite loop.

Assignment operation works as follows: first, the right expression is evaluated, in your case d / 10 is computed, after that this value is assigned to the variable on the left.